# Meteor entering route when calling a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Can someone explain to me why when I have collections code inside router will cause the route to be called when a method is called?

Consider the following [code](https://github.com/nelsyeung/playground/tree/master/meteor):

home.html

```
<template name="home">
    {{ duplicate }}
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="test" value="somevalue">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</template>
```

script.js

```
Template.home.events({
    'submit form': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Enter Meteor call');
        Meteor.call('createDoc', { 'test': e.target.test.value });
    }
});
```

route.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    console.log('Enter onBeforeAction');
    $('#loading').show();
    this.next();
});

Router.route('/', function () {
    console.log('Enter action');
    var foo = collection.findOne({ test: 'somevalue' }) ? 'true' : 'false';
    this.render('home', {
        data: {
            'duplicate' : foo
        }
    });

    Template.home.rendered = function () {
        console.log('Enter rendered');
        $('#loading').hide();
    };
});
```

methods.js

```
collection = new Mongo.Collection('collection');

Meteor.methods({
    createDoc: function (data) {
        console.log('Enter createDoc');
        collection.insert(data);
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I press submit on the form, after the method is called the router will activate, even though `e.preventDefault()` presents. The console log shows this behaviour clearly:

```
"Enter Meteor call" script.js:4:3
"Enter createDoc" methods.js:5:3
"Enter onBeforeAction" routes.js:2:2
"Enter action" routes.js:8:2
"Enter onBeforeAction" routes.js:2:2
"Enter action" routes.js:8:2
```

Furthermore, you can see that the router is called twice and that it never enters `Template.home.rendered`. This causes the loading div to appear and never leaves. I can confirm that data are being inserted correctly.

If I remove `collection.findOne()` in routes.js, however, this behaviour will disappear and everything works as expected.

### Questions

- Why is the route being called only when I have `collection.findOne()` inside the route?
- Why `collection.findOne({ test: 'somevalue' })` never returns anything inside the route? (I know how I can get around this by using Session variables and helpers in script.js, but I want to know exactly why)

This is causing a lot of unexpected behaviour in my app. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by others the problem you have arises from the fact that Meteor will reactively re-run code that runs in a reactive context, if and only if, that code issues a call to a reactive data source.

In your case, the call to `findOne` is a call to a reactive data source and the context in `Router.route('/', function () { // context });` is a reactive context.

There are two important tools that let you control this behavior: one is good design. Be aware of the reactivity and try to design your code around it.
The other is checking [Tracker.active](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_active) and using [Tracker.nonreactive](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive) to avoid reactivity inside a reactive data context.

This should answer your first question. As to why your `findOne` query never finds anything: have you published the data from the server to the client? Please check out [Publish-Subscribe](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/). You basically need:

```
// on the server
Meteor.publish('myPublication', function(author) {
     return collection.find();
});
// on the client
Meteor.subscribe('myPublication');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tracker documentation, that basically explained everything. I have no idea why I thought Iron Router can grab data without pub-sub...I guess it's from the mutitude of tutorials out there that only mention subscribe for a waitOn.

Answer (score 0):

The call to collection.findOne() inside the route is listening to any new changes on the database, every time text is saved on the database the query is run.

A possible solution:
Router.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  console.log('Enter onBeforeAction');
  $('#loading').show();
  this.next();
});



Router.route('/', {
  template: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('collection');
  },
  data: function() {
    var foo = collection.findOne({ test: 'somevalue' }) ? 'true' : 'false';
    return {
        'duplicate': foo
    };
  },
  action: function() {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

And a publish file on server/publish.js

```
Meteor.publish('collection', function () {
  return collection.find();
});
```

I hope this can help you solving your problem.
Best.